# Geolocation object seems to be empty after activating gps

Tags: typescript, geolocation, ionic3, angular5, google-geocoder

I want to show the current location of the mobile app user, when gps is on it shows me the right position. But when it is turned off and then press the button to turn it on it is not changing the variables value here below the value in my html:

```
<span ion-text class="text-11x no-margin" color="primary">{{yourLocation ? yourLocation : 'Zet je locatievoorzieningen aan'}}</span>
```

And when I click this button the gps is turned on:

```
<button color="primary" (click)="activateGpsSettings()">
```

And here is the activateGpsSettings():

```
activateGpsSettings() {
    this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {

        if (canRequest) {
            // the accuracy option will be ignored by iOS
            this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
                () => {
                    console.log('turned On');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.geoloactionDecode();
                    }, 500)
                },
                error => console.log('Error requesting location permissions', error)
            );
        }

    });
}
```

And the gealocationDecode():

```
 geoloactionDecode() {

    console.log('executed', this.geolocation);
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
        let lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        console.log('lat-lng', lat, lng);

        this.geocoderService.reverseGeocode(lat, lng)
            .then((data: any) => {
                this.geocoded = true;
                this.yourLocation = data;
                console.log('yourLocation:', this.yourLocation);
                // return this.yourLocation;
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                this.geocoded = true;
                this.yourLocation = error.message;
            });

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
}
```

And here is the geocode service:

```
  @Injectable()
export class GeocoderService {

   constructor(private geoCode  : NativeGeocoder){}

   /**
     *
     * Perform reverseGeocoding operation and return address details
     *
     * @public
     * @method reverseGeocode
     * @return {Promise}
     *
     */
   reverseGeocode(lat : number, lng : number) : Promise<any>
   {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      {
         this.geoCode.reverseGeocode(lat, lng)
         .then((result : NativeGeocoderReverseResult) =>
         {
            console.log(result[0])
            let str : string   = `Je huidige locatie is: ${result[0].thoroughfare}, ${result[0].locality}`;
            resolve(str);
         })
         .catch((error: any) =>
         {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error);
         });
      });
   }
}
```

But what seems so weird is that the function logs: executed With the `Geolocation object`, turned On, `executed empty Geolocation Object`

Like this: `Geolocation {}__proto__: IonicNativePlugin`

The first is because it is executed in the constructor than when I click the button it logs the console log in the `activateGpsSettings()` and than the `execute` log in the `geoloactionDecode()` method.

I cant figure it out why the it is not getting into `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then()` by cicking the button because than it turns on the gps...

Comment: not sure about ionic  there is a method `watchposition`  in ionic native geolocation which continuously observes the position of the device even it's turned off and on and moving . You should subscribe to the Observable returned by   `this.geolocation.watchposition()` to get update after the device is turned on . https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

Comment: @Niladri thanks for you comment, but I want it triggered when the user clicks the button.